# Problem of generating a standard normal distribution

Tags: statistics

> The algorithm for generating a standard normal random variable $Z$ is
>
> Step 1. Generate $Y$ with an exponential distribution at rate 1; that
>   is, generate $U$ and set $Y=-ln(U)$
>
> Step 2. Generate $U$. If $U \le e^{-(Y-1)^2/2}$, set $|Z| = Y$;
>   otherwise go back to Step 1.
>
> Step 3. Generate $U$. Set $Z = |Z|$ if $U \le 0.5$, set $Z = -|Z|$ if
>   $U > 0.5$.
>
> Provide an argument on showing that the above algorithm indeed leads
>   to a standard normal random variable $Z$.

This is the whole question that my prof. gave us in the statistics examination. But, besides *Rejection Method*, he taught NOTHING about how to generate a random variable, which makes me feel so annoyed... And I REALLY have NO IDEA about it.

Would you mind give me any hint or something similar, which I can know how to deal with it? A big thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the A/R method!

$$P(Z≤z)= P(Z≤z| Accept) = \frac {P(Z≤z,U≤e^{-\frac {(Y-1)^2}{2}})}{P(U≤e^{-\frac {(Y-1)^2}{2}})}$$

Now, we condition on the event {$Y=y$} to evaluate both probabilities:

$$P(U≤e^{-\frac {(Y-1)^2}{2}}) = \int_0^{\infty}P(U≤e^{-\frac {(Y-1)^2}{2}}|Y=y)f_Y(y)dy$$

$$=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\frac {(y-1)^2}{2}}e^{-y}dy= \int_0^{\infty}e^{\frac {(-y^2-1)}{2}}dy = e^{-\frac 12}\frac {\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}$$

from evaluating the Gaussian integral

without loss of generality, assume $z≥0$ Again, we use the same conditioning trick

$$P(Z≤z,U≤e^{-\frac {(Y-1)^2}{2}}) = P(Y≤z,U≤e^{-\frac {(Y-1)^2}{2}}|Z>0)P(Z>0) +P(-Y≤z,U≤e^{-\frac {(Y-1)^2}{2}}|Z≤0)P(Z≤0)$$

since we know {$-Y≤z$} with probability $1$ when $z≥0$

$$P(Z≤z,U≤e^{-\frac {(Y-1)^2}{2}})=\frac 12P(Y≤z,U≤e^{-\frac {(Y-1)^2}{2}}) + \frac 12P(U≤e^{-\frac {(Y-1)^2}{2}})$$

condition again:

$$=\frac 12\int_0^zP(U≤e^{-\frac {(Y-1)^2}{2}}|Y=y)f_Y(y)dy + \frac 12\int_0^{\infty}P(U≤e^{-\frac {(Y-1)^2}{2}}|Y=y)f_Y(y)dy$$

$$=\frac 12\int_0^ze^{-\frac {(y-1)^2}{2}}e^{-y}dy + \frac 12\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\frac {(y-1)^2}{2}}e^{-y}dy = \frac 12e^{-\frac 12}\int_0^ze^{-\frac {y^2}{2}}dy + \frac 12e^{-\frac 12}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\frac {y^2}{2}}dy = *$$

Because $e^{-\frac {y^2}{2}}$ is even,

$$* = \frac 12e^{-\frac 12}(\int_0^ze^{-\frac {y^2}{2}}dy + \int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{-\frac {y^2}{2}}dy) = \frac 12e^{-\frac 12}\int_{-\infty}^ze^{-\frac {y^2}{2}}dy$$

Put everything together...

$$P(Z≤z)= P(Z≤z| Accept) = \frac {P(Z≤z,U≤e^{-\frac {(Y-1)^2}{2}})}{P(U≤e^{-\frac {(Y-1)^2}{2}})} = \frac {\not {\frac 12}\not {e^{-\frac 12}}\int_{-\infty}^ze^{-\frac {y^2}{2}}dy}{\not {e^{-\frac 12}}\frac {\sqrt{2\pi}}{\not 2}} $$

$$= \frac {1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^ze^{-\frac {y^2}{2}}dy$$

As desired. Therefore, $Z$ is a standard Normal random variable with mean $0$ and variance $1$

The case where $z≤0$ is absolutely similar. Just note that $P(Y≤z, Accept|z≤0) = 0$

Comment: You should try using double dollar signs for equation to get display mode equations, making reading your answers much easier.

Comment: Then won't it drag on too much? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @nbubis, would you mind show me the problem?

Comment: @user237393, May I ask where is the coefficient $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from?  
$$P(Z≤z,U≤e^{-\frac {(Y-1)^2}{2}}) = P(Y≤z,U≤e^{-\frac {(Y-1)^2}{2}}|Z>0)P(Z>0) +P(-Y≤z,U≤e^{-\frac {(Y-1)^2}{2}}|Z≤0)P(Z≤0)$$

since we know {$-Y≤z$} with probability $1$ when $z≥0$

$$P(Z≤z,U≤e^{-\frac {(Y-1)^2}{2}})=\frac 12P(Y≤z,U≤e^{-\frac {(Y-1)^2}{2}}) + \frac 12P(U≤e^{-\frac {(Y-1)^2}{2}})$$